Is comparing two pointers to different char objects undefined in C?
This is code of memmove from https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/memmove.c
void *
memmove (void *dest, const void *src, size_t len)
{
  char *d = dest;
  const char *s = src;
  if (d < s)
    while (len--)
      *d++ = *s++;
  else
    {
      char *lasts = s + (len-1);
      char *lastd = d + (len-1);
      while (len--)
        *lastd-- = *lasts--;
    }
  return dest;
}

C11 standard says in 6.5.8. Relational operators:

When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the
address space of the objects pointed to. If two pointers to object types both point to the
same object, or both point one past the last element of the same array object, they
compare equal. If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object,
pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members
declared earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements with larger subscript
values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values. All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal. If the
expression P points to an element of an array object and the expression Q points to the
last element of the same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than
P. In all other cases, the behavior is undefined.

It looks like the code above compares pointers to two different objects:
  if (d < s)

i.e. the behavior is undefined, is this true? Or comparing pointers to chars are well-defined?

The standard library functions are not constrained by those rules because they form part of the implementation.

@IanAbbott, what if this would be my implementation of memmove, e.g. I don't use standard library's version, and wrote the same in my own .c file instead? Also, this doesn't seem to be implementation defined

@k1r1t0 GCC (and probably most other compilers) will behave as expected, even if it is undefined per standard: They will compare the numeric (totally-ordered) addresses represented by the pointers. If you don't need 100% portability, i.e. a strictly-conforming program, then I think that's an ok assumption to make.

If it is your own function then it would have UB because there is no well defined way to relatively compare random valid pointer values in the standard. They can only be compared for (in)equality.

The well-defined way would be to check for overlap first by iterating through the source/destination range and comparing against the beginning of the respective other range with ==, instead of using <.

In practice, most programs wouldn't use memmove from libgcc, but would use the one from the main C runtime library in the toolchain (e.g. glibc or msvcrt). That one would be more optimized for performance than the simple one in libgcc.

@user17732522 Yes, that would work, but would have more overhead than the forbidden relational test.

@k1r1t0: Re “Also, this doesn't seem to be implementation defined”: “Implementation defined” means the C standard requires an implementation to document something. However, there is no prohibition on an implementation defining anything it chooses to. When something is undefined by the C standard, that does not mean it must remain undefined. It only means the C standard is not defining it. An implementation is entirely free to define it. Undefined behavior does not mean you must not do something; it only means the C standard does not say anything about it.

@k1r1t0 - Historically, C was defined to handle segmented memory, where a pointer has two parts Segment:Offset. The Segment part is an index into a Descriptor table, and says nothing about where a memory block resides. This could also be changed by modifying the table, without changing the pointer. Thus comparing segments with < becomes meaningless. The standard reflects that by not saying what it means.

Implementations of a standard C library may require that compilers they are paired with define certain behaviors. In other words, a library implementation may state “This library relies on the fact that a compiler supports the relational operators on any two pointers to object types” and may then make use of that in its code.1
The fact that the C standard does not define a behavior does not prohibit a C implementation from defining the behavior and does not prohibit an implementation of the standard C library from requiring it be defined.

i.e. the behavior is undefined, is this true? Or comparing pointers to chars are well-defined?

Something can be both undefined and fully defined.
This is because, in the context of C, undefined is generally used to mean undefined behavior in the sense specified in the C standard. This sense of the word has only one meaning:

behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this document imposes no requirements [C 2018 3.4.3 1].

Here are some things this sense of the word “undefined” or the phrase “undefined behavior” does not mean:

It does not mean you may not use the construct or the data.

It does not mean the C implementation cannot define the behavior.

It does not mean you cannot examine and reason about the behavior based on things outside the C standard, such as the operating system, the hardware design, or the laws of physics.


So, a C implementation can define an “undefined” behavior. It is then a behavior undefined by the C standard but defined by the C implementation.
Footnote
1 Library implementations are often poorly documented and may fail to state such requirements explicitly or clearly. Nonetheless, this is the rationale for a library being able to use things that are not defined by the C standard alone.

@Eric Postpischil, don't you know if there's a flag that can control this behavior, especially for two pointer comparison? I found only -Wstrict-aliasing and -Wno-pointer-compare, but it doesn't seem they control this behavior, especially for GCC
